# Package autocompletion not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am using a minimum set of ROS on an embedded system, with also a minimum set of the `setup.sh` being executed, concretely:

```
export ROS_DISTRO=indigo
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 
export PATH=$PATH:$ROS_ROOT/bin 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROS_ROOT/lib 
export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$ROS_ROOT
```

I have it running properly. I have installed rosbash and tab completion works ok, although I have to manually source the setup file from rosbash package, following [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/66913/roscd-command-not-found-in-groovy-1204/)  . However, roslaunch completion is not working.

What could I be missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215279/package-autocompletion-not-working/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have it working, I was missing the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share/
```

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0